# I want to dynamically allocate css tags in my HTML. I'm also using Angular 5 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a table from data brought in as a JSON. This could be tonnes of data so I have a loop making all the rows in the table. I want to be able to click on a row and have that row expand showing the 2nd row with the list.extraInfo beneath it. Code looks like this:

```
<tbody *ngFor= " let list of lists, let i = index ">
   <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{i}}" class="clickable">
      <td > something </td>
      <td >{{i+1}}</td>
      <td >{{list.name}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
      <td colspan="3">
        <div id="{{i}}" class="collapse">
            {{list.extraInfo}}
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm well aware that having data-target="#{{i}}" and id="{{i}}" doesn't work, but I cannot find anywhere what it is I need to put there to get every row of the table to have a separate and distinct id number so that the collapse feature works on the row that you click on.

As it stands it opens the extraInfo row for the 1st row regardless of which row I click on.

Comment: I have also discovered that having data-target="word " and id="word" (note the space after word in the target) makes every row uncollapse when any row is clicked on.

Comment: what does `data-target="#{{i}}"` and `id="{{i}}"` produce? Is it outputting your incrementing index properly?

Comment: Page console gives errors.

Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.

Comment: are you using `ng-bootstrap`?

Comment: No Just using straight bootstrap 3.3.7

the line <td >{{i+1}}</td> outputs the index correctly.

Comment: does this work: `<tr data-toggle="collapse"  [attr.data-target]="'#'+ i" class="clickable">`

Comment: Yes! I changed the id to [attr.id]="i" and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: you're welcome friend. I just posted that as an answer

Comment: it worked, no worries. Also, you may want to read up on Template Reference Variables. I'd have to test, but it may be applicable to your case: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly brace syntax (`{{ }}`), also called interpolation, is meant for inner HTML. That is why `{{i+1}}` works in your `td` but not in your `tr` tag. To use a variable in a `<tr>` attribute, you don't need to wrap it in curly braces.

Secondly, the `Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.` error suggests that you need to use an attribute input binding instead:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#'+ i" class="clickable">
```